# Why does calling int() on a negative number return the integer under it?

Tags: vba, ms-access, integer, rounding

I stumbled upon a function in a Microsoft Access Database's VBA that uses this operation to round a number up :

[image: VBA operation]

For example, passing 12.34 to the `RoundUp()` function returned 13, and passing -12.34 returned -12, Meaning this function actually rounds up numbers, which is surprising.

[image: Results of the function calls]

The way this function works is obviously by taking the integer part of the negative of the passed number.

For 12.34 it should take the integer part of **-12.34**, so **-12**, not **-13**?

This was quite unexpected.

When I tried in python, not knowing what expecting, with this function :

[image: Python function]

Python showed me **12**.

[image: Results in python]

Meaning, when taking the integer part of **-12.34**, which is the negative of the passed number, it got **-12**.

Why does VBA do this ? Or am I mistaken on what should python's `int()` do ?

## **TL;DR** :

Trying to get the integer part of a negative number in VBA returns the number under it, as if it just rounded it down.

[image: definition]
[image: results]

Why ?

Comment: _this function actually rounds up numbers, which is surprising._ ... Eh, why do you think it was named as it is? Also, see my repository [VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round).

Comment: @Gustav This is a user-defined function, obviously it wouldn’t be named as it is if it didn’t do what it did, but I could see instantly that the code took the integer part of a float, which, to my understanding, was not equal to the integer under the float. But I understand now that there is a `Fix` function which does exactly what I expected `Int` to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how `Int` is [implemented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/int-fix-functions):

> `Int(number)`,`Fix(number)`
>
> The difference between `Int` and `Fix` is that if *number* is negative, `Int` returns the first negative integer less than or equal to *number*, whereas `Fix` returns the first negative integer greater than or equal to *number*.

Use `Fix` if you want the latter option.